# unable to add nuget packages in blank ASP.NET core project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've had Visual Studio 2015 generate me a blank ASP.NET Core app, with no template. However, when I right click on my project file and try to add Nuget packages, the option to do so is grayed out/disabled.

Does the latest version of Core use Bower packages instead of Nuget or something? When I open the Bower packages, that list is empty as well.

[image: error message screen Visual Studio 2015, Core app]

Comment: Do the "Restore Package" first

Comment: I've already tried the Restore packages option before (and just now again), but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are you running Visual Studio Update 3?
>
> Do you have the latest .NET Core templates installed?
>
> Do you have the latest 'preview' .NET Core tooling installed?

If you do have the `dotnet` CLI installed, open a command/powershell prompt in the project directory and run `dotnet restore`.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2 & 3. I think so, but will download again just to be safe. I opened cmd and ran the command, but it didn't help either.

Comment: It didn't help? Please be more specific. Was dotnet a recognised command? Was there a network error? We can't help without specifics.

Comment: Right, apologies. It did recognize the command, and it was executed. Packages were restored according to the log lines. In fact, I now read the lines and it said something about a lock. Sure enough my project was still debugging, hence why the option is grayed out. I feel stupid. Thanks for your help nonetheless!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Happens to everyone.